# How to use Compass with symfony?

Tags: symfony1, sass, compass-sass

I'm currently experimenting with symfony, SASS, and Compass.

I use [sfSassyCssPlugin](http://github.com/vicb/sfSassyCssPlugin) to automatically compile my `.scss` files.

- If I want to use Compass with this plugin, do I need to modify it to use another compiler (Compass instead of SASS)?
- What's the best way to use Compass with symfony projects?

Answer (score 2):

I've never used the sfSassyCSSPlugin, but, after looking it up, Compass seems like a much simpler use case to me; I'd probably use it in lieu of the plugin. That said, I've never been a fan of Symfony so my judgment may be clouded. Compass doesn't worry about your app's runtime. You edit, you compile, you run. No Symfony config files to mess with, no operational changes between different environments, etc.

Compass will also "watch" for changes and just compile each time one of your `.scss` or, my preference, `.sass` files changes. You don't have to give it a second thought.

Comment: sfSassCSSPlugin is used to automatically compile changed .sass files , to give feedback about the compilation and to make the compilation process configurable from project configuration files. I like those features. When you say that compass is 'whatching' for changes, do you mean that it only compiles those files that were changed, but you still have to manually start the compilation process? That flow is not that userfriendly when working in a team with designers, who need to see their changes when they change their code - hassle-free...

Comment: Compass supports a `compass watch` subcommand that immediately (well, within one second) re-compiles any source files that it sees changed. But I think you could use another tool to kick off a `compass compile` when files have changed.

Comment: +1, compass watch is very convenient. It just runs in the background (in a terminal window) while you develop.

Answer (score 0):

sfSassyCSSPlugin looks like an extra layer of complexity wrapped around Compass. That plug-in is for symfony 1.x, with which you're better off using Compass directly.

Navigate to the project directory and issue the following command to set things up:

`compass create web --css-dir=css`

And then run next command, which will watch the project and compile the CSS whenever there's a change to the Sass:

`compass watch web`

But if you've moved up to Symfony2 and have CSS spread out across multiple bundles, then this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11324725/1090474 answer, using Assetic, is a better solution.